# Create a Matrix with random position

Tags: python, random

I am creating a matrix with this

```
def letsplay(m,n):
    matrix = [[ '.' for m in range(10)] for n in range(10)]
    for sublist in matrix:
        s = str(sublist)
        s = s.replace('[', '|').replace(']', '|').replace(',', "")
        print(s)
```

that returns

```
>>> '.'.'.'.'.'.'.'.'.'.'
    '.'.'.'.'.'.'.'.'.'.'
    ...
    ...
```

That creats a matrix 10x10. and Now I want to add within the matrix to random position with a probability = prob, the prob should be entered by the user, and return for the random posstions a 'N'.

Comment: When you choose a random Position in the given Matrix, the probability for each spot will be exactly the same, otherwise the position would not be random. Also a probabilty of 5 simply doesn't exists, probabilities are all in a 0-1 range. The probability of choosing a certain spot in your matrix is 0.01

Comment: yeah @Stefan youre right

Comment: @Stefan for ex minesweeper

Comment: I think there is a given prob or not

Comment: how is prob calculated?

Answer (score 1):

How about using a probability matrix:

```
probs = numpy.random.random_sample((10, 10))
data = numpy.empty(probs.shape, dtype='S1')
data.fill('.')
data[probs < threshold] = 'N'
```

where `threshold` is a variable that you choose, for example, 0.05 for a 5% chance.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure what prob=5 would mean, probabilities range from 0 to 1?
I think there's two parts to your question.

- change a random element of the matrix

  `matrix[random.randrange(10)][random.randrange(10)] = 'N'`
- have a number of elements changed in the matrix, based on a probability.

  ```
  import random
  prob = 0.01
  numNs = prob*10*10 # because e.g. 1% chance in 10x10 matrix = 1 field
  for i in range(numNs):   
    changed = False   
    while not changed:
      x = random.randrange(10)
      y = random.randrange(10)
      if not matrix[x][y] == 'N': # if not already changed
        matrix[x][y] = 'N'
        changed = True
  ```

Comment: that is a mistake with prob 5

Comment: but only random positions should get N

Comment: well that assignment to matrix I showed, it assigns 'N' to exactly one position in the matrix.

Comment: what do you mean with change, if you look at minesweeper there are also more bomb field than one

Comment: yes, that's why you need to split the problem into actually changing one field (changing = setting to "N"), and deciding how often you want to change a field. I showed you how to do the first step and explained why I can't answer the second one - because you don't describe clearly how this is supposed to be decided

Comment: ok so we have a function that creates a mxn matrix and now with a p = probability in any desired (x, y) position may a N.

Comment: but prob is now defined

Comment: i get an error that NameError: name 'prob' is not defined

Comment: well you have to define it... added to sample