# Set on random position

Tags: python

I want to create a minesweeper so make this code

```
def mines(m,n):
    matrix = [[ '*' for m in range(10)] for n in range(10)]
    for sublist in matrix:
        s = str(sublist)
        s = s.replace('[', '|').replace(']', '|').replace(',', "")
        print(s)
```

and that creates a grid 10x10 and that looks like:

```
| * | * | * | * | * | * | * | * | * | * |
| * | * | * | * | * | * | * | * | * | * |
| * | * | * | * | * | * | * | * | * | * |
| * | * | * | * | * | * | * | * | * | * |
| * | * | * | * | * | * | * | * | * | * |
| * | * | * | * | * | * | * | * | * | * |
| * | * | * | * | * | * | * | * | * | * |
| * | * | * | * | * | * | * | * | * | * |
| * | * | * | * | * | * | * | * | * | * |
| * | * | * | * | * | * | * | * | * | * |
```

and now I want to get on random positions a 'O' I know that i have to use random but but don't know how to add it

Comment: Which bit are you struggling with? Generating the random position? Or adding the mine at that position? Have you read the [docs for `random`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html)?

Comment: Have you tried Googling how to random in python... I am sure there is something there that could help.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I know to use randrange

Comment: Why are you requiring m & n in your function call? Did you maybe mean to make that the limits on your columns and rows?

Comment: So where's the code where you use it, and where do you actually have problems?

Comment: @mauve yes  but I've tried it and don't work but it did what it should

Comment: @jonrsharpe it works with randrange but whats the reason tjat only one position is changing

Comment: this looks spectacularly similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23591602/create-a-matrix-with-random-position

Comment: Well how many are you trying to change? Are you generating new random numbers each time, checking they haven't been used? **Show the code.** We're good, but not psychic.

Comment: @Nicolas78 yes it looks like but your suggestion does not work

Comment: @jonrsharpe if you look at the minesweeper game there are random mines  and not only one mine

Comment: well reposting the same question sure isn't the way to go about this...

Comment: Yes, thank you, I'm familiar with minesweeper. However, I can't (always!) fix buggy code sight unseen, so please update your question with your actual code.

Comment: @jonrsharpe What do you think of the idea of using `random.sample(range(100), x)` to get `x` at random places in a 1-D list, and then making that list two-dimensional?

Comment: @jonrsharpe so I've updated it

Comment: @AlexThornton that's a good idea, you can easily use `%` to convert to the coordinates

Comment: @user3629826 I don't understand your question

Comment: @jonrsharpe I mean instead of random.randerange to use sample how to use it to every line

Comment: @user3629826 that is not much clearer; what does "to every line" mean? Do you want one bomb on each row of the matrix?

Comment: @user3629826 My answer now uses a different approach, give it a try.

Comment: @jonrsharpe it is really easy to use sample for a list and get random numbers but we have 10x10 and there are 10 rows

Comment: @user3629826 That's why I have employed some basic arithmetic in my answer to extract the x and y values for the position.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would do, using [`random.sample`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/random.html#random.sample) to get unique coordinates:

```
positions = random.sample(range(100), amount_you_want)
for coord in positions:
    matrix[coord%10][coord//10] = 'O'
```

and of course, `import random` at the top.

Comment: so I have to understand that : sample takes 10 random postions of 
of the total 100 but what does matrix[coord//10][coord%10] = 'O'

Comment: @user3629826 So a given `coord` can be any value from 0-99. The `//` is floor division by 10, so it extracts the 10s value which we will use as one dimension. Then the `%` (modulus) takes away all the full 10s leaving us with just a unit which we will use from the other dimension. Then we just insert with those.

Comment: I love your `random.sample` approach. I'm awful at coming up with those algorithmic approaches. For more versatility consider `for coord in random.sample(range(WIDTH*HEIGHT), NUM_MINES): matrix[coord//WIDTH][coord%WIDTH] = "O"`

Comment: @AdamSmith We all have those 'why didn't I think of that?' moments I suppose. One might not notice when they think of something clever themselves. Besides, you're a professional programmer- it's not really your job to come up with algorithms but to implement them. Also, perhaps I only thought of it because we revised algorithms in Computer Science today :).

Comment: @AlexThornton can't tell if small dig on programming versus compsci or... ;) Good work!

Comment: Alex we have now a coord how to check if one x y is euqal  'O' I mean a bomb

Comment: @user3629826 `if matrix[x][y] == 'O':`

Comment: but its also possbile with for .... or?

Comment: and also your x and y are undefined

Comment: I thougth doing it with range

Comment: because I trying to check if it is a bomb if not it should print out how many neighboring bomb every postion have

Answer (score 1):

I'm gonna refactor your code a bit because I think you're missing a huge opportunity to learn OOP.

```
class Tile(object):
    """Tile defines an individual square of the board. This is an ABC, don't
instantiate it yourself but use Mine and Empty"""
    shape = "!"
    def __init__(self):
        self.flagged = False
    def __str__(self):
        return "?" if self.flagged else self.shape

class Mine(Tile):
    shape = "O"

class Empty(Tile):
    shape = "."

class MineSweeperBoard(object):
    def __init__(self, size, num_mines):
        self.max_x, self.max_y = size
        self.num_mines = num_mines
        self.field = [[Empty() for y in range(self.max_y)] for x in range(self.max_x)]
        self.generateMines()

    def generateMines(self):
        from random import randrange
        for _ in range(self.num_mines):
            while True:
                x, y = randrange(self.max_x), randrange(self.max_y)
                if not isinstance(self.field[y][x], Mine):
                    self.field[y][x] = Mine()
                    break

    def run(self):
        """Runs the game of minesweeper"""
        # implement your runnable code!
```

Comment: Holy cow, credit where it's due, the effort people are willing to put in for others on this site!

Comment: @AlexThornton I kind of like implementing somewhat silly ideas here. Keeps me fresh. Most of my actual coding at work could probably be better handled by bash so it's nice to dig my teeth into something

Comment: +1 Purely for the time you put in for absolutely nothing back.

Answer (score 0):

This line of code:

```
matrix[random.randrange(10)][random.randrange(10)] = 'O' # genrates the bomb***
```

only runs once, so only ever generates one bomb. To generate a random number of bombs, between `x` and `y-1`, wrap it in a `for` loop:

```
for _ in range(x, y):
    matrix[random.randrange(10)][random.randrange(10)] = 'O' # generates the bomb
```

If you need a particular number of bombs, note that this can create overlapping bombs (same coordinates more than once) - if this is a problem, you could switch to a `while` loop until the right number are generated.